# replace <image> by video

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an `SVG` which has a simplified structure like that:

```
 <svg viewbox="0 0 1000 2000">
   <image width="1024" height="2048" transform="<matrix A>" … />
 </svg>
```

And I want to replace the image with a html5 `<video>` element, usign the `<foreignObject>` like so:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 1000 2000">
   <g transform="<matrix A>">
     <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
       <video style="display:block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
         <source src="…" type="…">
        </video>
     </foreignObject>
   </g>
   <!--
     <image width="1024" height="2048" transform="<matrix in here>" … />
   -->
 </svg>
```

Therefore I have this code:

```
 [...document.querySelectorAll('image')].forEach(img => {
   const 
     g     = document.createElementNS('…', 'g'),
     fo    = g.appendChild(document.createElementNS('…', 'foreignObject')),
     video = fo.appendChild(document.createElement('video')),
     src   = video.appendChild(document.createElement('source'))
   ;

   g.setAttribute('transform', img.getAttribute('transform'));

   fo.setAttribute('x', 0);
   fo.setAttribute('y', 0);
   fo.setAttribute('width', '100%');
   fo.setAttribute('height', '100%');

   video.style.cssText = `
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     left: 100px;
     background-color: #00ff00;
   `

   video.setAttribute('width', 100);
   video.setAttribute('height', 100);

   img.parentNode.appendChild(g);
   img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
 });
```

Basically everything works fine so far, but I cannot make the `<video>` appear at the same location an size as the image. The specs say:

**(I)**

> […] The included foreign graphical content is subject to SVG transformations, filters, clipping, masking and compositing […]

**(II)**

> The HTML parser treats elements inside the ‘foreignObject’ equivalent to elements inside an HTML document fragment. […]

Taking **(I)** into account: By replacing the image with a `<g>` which has all the transformations copied over from the image, the video should »live in the coordinate space« than.

Taking **(II)** into account, the `<video>` should become the root node of a new Document Fragment, and fit into the given area.

But the result looks like that:

[image]

Whereby: The Black Area represents the entire SVG, the white Area the overall HTML document, which includes the the SVG. Both green areas are/seam to be the video, whereby the larger one is the one I would like to have the video.

Why is that/What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Since this went too far I created this basic svg:

```
<svg 
  width="200"
  height="200"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
    </clipPath>  
  </defs>
  <rect 
    x="0" 
    y="0" 
    width="200" 
    height="200" 
    style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:none" 
    clip-path="url(#clip)" />

  <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" >
      <video 
        autoplay="" 
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <source src="/path/to/a/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
  <text x="100" y="100">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

What works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chromium. I can manage to get the video cropped by adding `style="clip-path: url(#clip)"` to the video, but the `<text>` does not appear in front of the video, in chromium.

Considering the coordinates of the video, this works:

```
const 
  { top, 
    left, 
     width, 
     height } = foreignObject.getBoundingClientRect()
  ;


Object.entries({ width, height}).forEach(
  ([k,v]) => video.setAttribute(k,v)
);

video.style.left = `${left}px`;
video.style.top = `${top}px`;
```

Comment: Why not use `replaceChild`

Comment: That's not the problem here…

Comment: Not much time to dig, but `<foreignObject width="100%" ...` shouldn't it be `<foreignObject width="1024"`? + foreignObject add some padding to their inner docs (IIRC not the same between implementations...)

Comment: @philipp Still a valid question

Comment: Why not use css transforms directly if it is all your svg is intended for?

Comment: @Kaiido The SVG shown here extremely shortened the video itself is meant to be a kind of layer within the overall thing. I honestly do not really care where to apply the `x, y ,width, height` values, as long as it looks right. So how can I obtain those values to be sure that they are right? Than: where to put those…

Comment: Maybe you don't care, but the svg renderer does. If your <image> had absolute values, then your foreignObject must have too.

Comment: @Kaiido not sure what mean by »absolute values« in this context. But as it turns out the whole thing seams to be an browser based issue. I guess FF does it right, but chromium doesn't…

Comment: Relative length: % em vw etc. Absolute length px in cm and svg magical unit.

Comment: @Kaiido well that's right, didn't take that into accout, however, please see the updates, I could figure out how to get the coordinates…

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1u5wxqeb/

Comment: @Kaiido Wow! That works in Chromium as well! SO it seams to be the `webm` encoding, or is there anything different I have not seen?

Comment: no it is the foreignObject  the culprit in the fiddle I'm doing all through CSS.

Comment: excuses… Must have overseen that…

Answer (score -1):

Your viewport is 1000x2000 but the image is 1024x2048. I think that will clip your image. Might be part of the confusion.

Next: Images scale more freely than videos since you usually want to preserve the aspect ration of the video. That's why you get black borders when the video size doesn't fit the container. Make sure that the video size, the image size and the SVG viewport all agree.

I'm also a bit skeptical that a browser can apply all SVG transformations to video. At least in the past, browsers wouldn't render video themselves but reserve a rectangular area in the page and send the coordinates of this area to a video renderer (which could be in another process using an overlay window). If you can't get this to work, try to replace the whole SVG with the video.

Also, instead of doing this in JavaScript, build a small local HTML file that you can quickly tweak until the video looks correct. When it works, then start with code that can transform between the two. Otherwise, you're opening too many cans of worms.

**[Update 1]**

Welcome to Hell. Stay a while ...

You can try to use the developer tools to find out what Chromium is doing in this case. Maybe create a second local test case where you try to position a `<div>`  with some text over the video. If that doesn't work, then Chromium is using an external renderer for this type of video.

This looks the same on the screen but behind the scenes, Chromium is asking another process to position another window on the screen in such a way that it looks as if it was part of the page. If you have a tool which can show you the coordinates of all application windows on the screen, you can see that there is one which stays on top of your browser window. Clicks go to that Window, Chromium can't see them and it can't render anything in front of that window because it's a window of someone else (just like you wouldn't want Chromium to render over a text editor that happens to be open over the browser window).

Options:

1. Convert to a format which Chromium can render by itself. See https://www.chromium.org/audio-video for a list. That's probably only VP8, VP9 and Theora (= any "open" video format). H.264 and MPEG-4 might not work because film studios panic that you could steal their precious.
2. Use text overlay where it works and move the text below the video where it doesn't.
3. Use a process on the server serving the video files to stamp the text into the video before passing it to the browser. Some video formats have support for subtitles which can be abused for this if you don't need anything too fancy. This would prevent the need to reencode the video.
4. Display a text and ask visitors to install a browser where it works.

Comment: They use of matrix transformations on this image, assuming it clips is a big assumption, then the transformation is applied on the foreignObject, browser should apply there (and CSS transforms are actually more powerful than svg ones)

Comment: In case the video is rendered by a video renderer, what sounds reasonable in this scenario, how can I »send coordinates« to it??

Comment: Don't worry this renderer thing is non sense, how would they apply layouts, filters etc if that was the case? Nowadays everything is painted on canvases. And CSS is even able to apply 3d transforms to videos.

Comment: @philipp Almost no external video renderer can do this; they can just draw into a rectangle on the screen. From the OS perspective, it was two programs with one window each. That's why applying filters or putting HTML control in front didn't work for a long time.

Comment: I'd try to add the video outside of the SVG. SVG is messy and had a lot of problems in the past. Try to replace the whole SVG and use CSS to place / style your video.

Comment: That's unfortunate, because there should a clip-path applied as well. Additionally there is text above the video.  Putting the video into the html requires me to do a lot of additional coding…

Comment: The text over video already works? That's a good sign. Makes me think that the video material is just the wrong size. Can you confirm that the video has the exact same pixel size and ratio as the image?

Comment: @philipp Added some ideas. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thanks!